# In R 3.0.1 functions in package not available any more

Tags: r

I upgraded to R 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 a few days ago and nothing seems to work any more... :( The most annoying thing is that after I compile my packages under R 3.0.1 functions in the package are just not there any more (like they are not exported). This all worked in R 2.15.3 and before...

I have created a very simple reproducible example here https://github.com/SamoPP/packageTest . If you build the package and load it using require(packageTest) you can not use a simple function in it...

The problem is:

```
> require(packageTest)
....
> printTestPackage()
Error: could not find function "printTestPackage"
> packageTest::printTestPackage()
Error: 'printTestPackage' is not an exported object from 'namespace:packageTest'
> packageTest:::printTestPackage()
[1] "Testing!!! And it works."
```

How to persuade R 3.0.1 to automatically export all functions in all *.R files in ./R/ folder what used to be default behaviour before R 3.0.1?

What am I missing here?

I hope the message is not: You need to explicitly export all functions in packages after R version 3.0... Since this means I can write export for a week or two... I hope there is a workaround.

Thanks for any recommendations/hints/fixes/...

Edit:
Changing NAMESPACE file in such a way to add a "general" (export everything not starting with a dot) export pattern via

```
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
```

solves the problem for me since I do not have time to explicitly write export for every single function I want to export. Until next change.... :)

Still looking for more elegant/"right way" solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NAMESPACE` file doesn't export anything. Only the functions exported in the `NAMESPACE` do become visible. See the [section on namespaces in Writing R extension](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces).

If you want your function to be visible, put the following in the `NAMESPACE` file:

```
export(printTestPackage)
```

In fact, the need to explicitly export functions via `NAMESPACE` was not introduced in R 3.0 but earlier, I guess at least R 2.15 or rather R 2.14.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, yes, NAMESPACE was introduced but was not mandatory in previous versions I guess. Unfortunately I have created so many functions in so many packages I can not explicitly export them one by one using "export(functionName)"... Looking for workarounds. One was found looking at the docs.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it might be the case, but my setup stopped working only after upgrade to R 3.0.1 . Offical docs here http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces  say that "Prior to R 2.14.0, namespaces were optional in packages: a default namespace was generated on installation in 2.14.x and 2.15.x. As from 3.0.0 a namespace is mandatory."

Comment: Aha. So, we were kind of both right. By the way, I don't mind an upvote/accept for helping you.

Comment: @Samo, you can export everything by putting this in your `NAMESPACE`: `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` (which is the default NAMESPACE if you create your package with `package.skeleton()`).

Comment: @GSee Thanks. Once again. This really brings back everything back to working state.